# How can one sort two registers without leaving an entangled ancilla behind used for comparison?

Tags: quantum-circuit, arithmetic

If we have an state $\alpha|abc\rangle + \beta|bad\rangle$, and we know that $a<b$, how can we obtain state $\alpha|abc\rangle + \beta|abd\rangle$ without entangled ancillas, if we don't know $c$ or $d$?

With an ancilla it is simple: just use it for comparison purposes and controlled on it, swap the first and second register. But then we cannot uncompute it.

Comment: What values can a to d take? 0 and 1 or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do that. It would violate reversibility.

What you *can* do, from a larger scale algorithm design perspective, is make sure the state you're operating on is a state where this is not a problem. For example, if the state is invariant under permutation, sorting it will produce comparison state qubits that are separable from the sorted item qubits. ["Improved techniques for preparing eigenstates of fermionic Hamiltonians"](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41534-018-0071-5) uses sorting networks on states with that property (or exponentially close approximations of that property, rather).